# Proper complex Q promises, chaining then and spread

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, q

I'm getting into Q promises with my express routing, and just wanted to see if I'm working with them the proper way using this example. The code works, but it seems like it could be chained better.

Basically I want the productPromise code to run first, and `if(product.nModified === 0)` I want the route to end with `res.json({message: 'Produc...'});` and have the callback within `Q.spread` not run at all.

I believe currently both `productPromise` and `userQuery` are being evaluated by `Q.spread`. This is fine in the example, but in a case where `userQuery` is intensive, I would want it to not be evaluated unless necessary.

**EDIT:** I would just chain `then`'s but, I need to access the return values of both promises (product, user) within the final (`spread`) callback.

```
router.post('/cartAddProduct', auth, function(req, res, next){
  var newCartItem = {
    product: req.body._id,
    quantity: req.body.quan
  };

  var userQuery = User.update({username: req.payload.username, 'cart.product': {$ne: newCartItem.product}},
    {$push: {cart: newCartItem}}).exec();

  var productQuery = Product.findById({_id:req.body._id, quantity: {$gte: newCartItem.quantity}}).exec();

  var productPromise = productQuery
    .then(function(product){
      if(product.nModified === 0) {
        res.json({message: 'Product no longer has sufficient quantity in stock.'});
      }else{
        return product;
      }
    });


  Q.spread([productPromise, userQuery],function(product, user){
    if(!user.nModified){
      res.json({message: 'Item is already in your cart.'});
    }else{
      product.quantity -= newCartItem.quantity;
      product.save();
      res.json({message: 'Item added to cart', addedProduct: newCartItem});
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Let me know if I can explain any better.
Cheers!

Comment: It's not `spread` that evaluates them, it's the `User.update(…)` call that starts the operation.

Comment: In what case exactly do you consider the query unnecessary?

Comment: I don't think your script works, if `product.nModified === 0` then you are still calling `res.json` twice or getting an error when setting properties on `undefined`.